# Strange issue with Nginx compiled from source and Nginx from official Fedora repository

Tags: nginx, vps, php-fpm

TL;DR Nginx, compiled from source, had trouble process .php files, while with the same PHP-FPM configuration, nginx , from official Fedora repository, worked like a charm on DigitalOcean 512MB Fedora 21 x64 VPS. What is the reason behind it?

I am using DigitalOcean 512MB Droplet with Fedora 21 x64 VPS.

I compiled Nginx from source and installed it in /opt/nginx/. Here's the output of `/opt/nginx/nginx -V`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.7.10
built by gcc 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/opt/nginx --sbin-path=/opt/nginx --without-http_autoindex_module --without-http_browser_module --without-http_empty_gif_module --without-http_geo_module --without-http_map_module --without-http_referer_module --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_split_clients_module --without-http_ssi_module --without-http_userid_module --without-http_uwsgi_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_ssl_module --without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_smtp_module --with-openssl=openssl --with-pcre=pcre --with-zlib=zlib --with-ipv6
```

Till now, I was using it to serve only static pages. Today, I installed php-fpm from official Fedora repository and configured nginx (the one that I compiled from source with the above given configuration) to pass .php pages to PHP-FPM via unix sockets.

Unfortunately, I received the `No input file specified` error. I've previously faced this issue, so I knew what to do. I quickly changed the file permission but it still received the same error.

After searching for hours and trying every possible solution, I was still receiving the same error. I found [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.openbsd.misc/193671) to be sharing somewhat same issue.

I thought why not give Nginx from offical Fedora repository a try. I installed it. Stopped the previous nginx (compiled from source) with `/opt/nginx/nginx -s stop` and configured the new nginx (from official Fedora repository) to pass .php to PHP-FPM to the same unix sockets.

And it worked.

My question is "Why did nginx (compiled from source) had trouble processing php while nginx, from official Fedora repository, worked like charm?". Could this be SELinux?

EDIT: More information about my setup.

Nginx (compiled from source)

- Installed in /opt/nginx/
- Serves web content from /srv

Nginx (from official Fedora repository)

- Default installation, usually /usr/sbin/nginx
- Serves content from /usr/share/nginx/html/

Comment: misconfiguration of php-fpm

Comment: No @alexus. I've confirmed it. Configuration is all OK. The same configuration works in my local server.

Comment: well obviously not, as you're getting `No input file specified` and that's very common mistake pointing to misconfiguration of `php-fpm`.

Comment: You are right. "No input file specified" is very common error. But the same PHP-FPM configuration works with the nginx from official Fedora repository but not with the nginx that I have compiled from source.

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Guys, I think the culprit could be SELinux. May be SELinux isn't allowing PHP-FPM to access /srv directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it finally.

SELinux was forbidding PHP-FPM from accessing the file since web content was served from /srv.

Running the following command

```
sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /srv/
```

solved the issue.

Thank you everyone for helping.

Reference: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/